# Mule 4 - Until Successful - increase wait time for each iteration

Tags: mule, mule4

In my application i am making a HTTP call to read data from external system. I wanted to make repeated trails until 3 times with an interval until i get the success response. I am using Mule's  component to do this. below is the code.

```
<until-successful maxRetries="3" millisBetweenRetries="10000">
   <http:request method="GET"></http:request>
</until-successful>
```

This code is making 3 trails with an interval of 10 seconds.

However, i wanted to increase wait time for each iteration.
i.e. I want  component to wait for 10s on first iteration, 20s on second iteration and 30s on third iteration.

Is there any option to do this with  component.
Please suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do this out of the box. The wait time can be an expression but I don't think you can change the values in each iteration.

Comment: You could try to implement your own custom scope with the Mule SDK.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this happen by nesting `<until-successful>` scopes with different delays.  Not the most elegant but at least it uses out of the box components!

```
<flow name="pavanFlow">
    <http:listener doc:name="go" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="go"/>
    <until-successful maxRetries="1" doc:name="Third Retry" millisBetweenRetries="30000">
        <until-successful maxRetries="1" doc:name="Second Retry" millisBetweenRetries="20000">
            <until-successful maxRetries="1" doc:name="First Retry" millisBetweenRetries="10000">
                <flow-ref doc:name="attemptFlow" name="attemptFlow" />
            </until-successful>
        </until-successful>
    </until-successful>
</flow>
<flow name="attemptFlow">
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Trying" message="Trying"/>
    <raise-error doc:name="SOMEFAILURE" type="X:SOMEFAILURE"/>
</flow>
```